# How to send POST Request to XML to get data?

Tags: php, xml, http-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [POST XML to URL with PHP and Handle Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471506/post-xml-to-url-with-php-and-handle-response)

There is an XML to return city list by POSTing province id. (it accepts the id by POST)
**http://example.com/get_city_list.xml**

```
<cities>
  <city>
    <id></id>
    <name></name>
  </city>

  <city>
    <id></id>
    <name></name>
  </city>

  <city>
    <id></id>
    <name></name>
  </city>
<cities>
```

How can I send out the province id (by POST REQUEST) to the XML?

I am using php 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/path/to/form");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'foo' => 'foo foo foo',
    'bar' => 'bar bar bar',
    'baz' => 'baz baz baz'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```